# ES6 Mocha - Syntax Error

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I have authored a react-native app using ES6 and testing with Mocha, but I am running into basic syntax errors when running my tests. It seems to be okay with my `import` syntax, but it chokes on `const {` in my dependency (https://github.com/APSL/react-native-button) I have.

My code:

`import Button from 'apsl-react-native-button';`

Here is my error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

And the code from my dependency:

`const React = require('react');
const {
  PropTypes
} = React;`

And lastly my `mocha.opts`:

`--compilers js:babel-core/register
--require react-native-mock/mock
--require babel-polyfill
--reporter spec
--recursive`

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "dependency" part? If you are using a transpiler, usually transpilers ignore anything in `node_modules`, and Node v5 doesn't support destructuring. The problem might solve itself if you use Node v6.

Comment: Updated question with clarification

Comment: Are you  using react-native version 0.26.x ? Are you sure apsl-react-native-button is compatible with it ? The import for React and Component has changed from 0.26